# html element in placeholder

Tags: html, placeholder

I have this input

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
```

Since my form has no labels and I depend on placeholder, is it possible to put an element like

```
<sup>*</sup>
```

so that I can show to the users that this field required.

I tried but it didn't work.

Is there a way to do that?

**my form**

http://www.itbotics.com/contact.php

Comment: Can't you use `<input ><sup>*</sup>`?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: satpal its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a label:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
<label for="Name">*</label>
```

or you could add * after the placeholder text. any reason for not using labels? they're good practice

Comment: Thanks for that, I just want to try something new and cleaner form

Comment: yeh forms always look cleaner without labels but its bad for a lot of reasons, mostly accessibility, google like's pages that are more accessible to everyone so leaving out labels will affect your page ranking

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use label:

> css code:

```
.required::before {
    content: "*";
    color:red;
}
```

> html code:

```
<span class="required"></span>
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
```

Comment: Ill try this one sir